# How to control the pop up java execution in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, pdfbox

I am using PDFbox as an external library in Java in eclipse, every time I use some class/method from PDFBox, a java execution window would appear, just like my program calls another java program (it is the same java window when I use PDFBox in terminal.)

But this does not happen when I use other libraries and I feel like this process slows down my program (maybe not true). And I just do not like it? Anyone has idea why this happens and how to control it?

See the rightmost icon? It appears every time I run my program with PDFbox involved. 
[image]

Here is a piece of code I used to extract text,

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file_name);
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    int num_of_pages = document.getNumberOfPages();
    int begin_page = num_of_pages - (num_of_pages/5+1);
    stripper.setStartPage(begin_page); 
    String all_text = stripper.getText(document);
```

Comment: That is not normal behavior of pdfbox. Are you sure you use a genuine pdfbox jar?

Comment: Maybe mention what version you are using, and the name of the jars.

Comment: I am using the ones downloaded from here. At beginning, I used only pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar, it worked, but java window pop up, then I thought maybe I should use pdfbox-1.8.9.jar and fontbox and jempbox, but the same thing happens again. In detail, I added jar into building path and use the class and methods according to document. Is there anything wrong or did I use the right file? @mkl

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am using the ones downloaded from here. At beginning, I used only pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar, it worked, but java window pop up, then I thought maybe I should use pdfbox-1.8.9.jar and fontbox and jempbox, but the same thing happens again. In detail, I added jar into building path and use the class and methods according to document. Is there anything wrong or did I use the right file?

Comment: using the pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar is usually a good idea, because it has most of what is needed, however the app also runs from the command line to do cool things. I don't use eclipse, but I notice this in your text: "...when I use PDFBox in terminal". Maybe a wrong theory - could it be that you use some shortcut that will launch this "when I use PDFBox in terminal" instead of running your application?

Comment: I don't think so, actually my code on this part is quite simple, it just instantiate a new PDdocument and extract text from it. I didn't execute any terminal related command. Just to make it clear, I have uploaded a pic in the original post. @TilmanHausherr

Comment: *just instantiate a new PDdocument and extract text from it* - I've done that many times from eclipse but there never opened a terminal. Thus, you most likely did something wrong.

Comment: The code looks completely normal but the behavior is not. Hmm. You say each time you use some class/method from PDFBox, a java execution window would appear. So during the run of your code above, 5 windows open?

Comment: No, for example, I tried to extract 5 documents in my program, and everytime I run my program, one java execution window would appear, not 5. But the first document for extraction is also slower than the others (not because of the document itself), I guess this is because the window pop up... @mkl

Comment: Do you extract from those 5 documents in one Java loop? Or are those 5 distinct application starts?

Comment: in one java loop, not 5 application starts, and there is one window pop up. @mkl

Comment: If there is one window pop up for one application start, this might be simply an instance of a JRE running your program. Which properties are configured for the execution of that code from eclipse?

Comment: Sorry, I am a rookie, I don't understand what do you mean by "Which properties are configured for the execution of that code from eclipse?" could you give some hint? @mkl

Comment: *properties are configured for the execution of that code from eclipse* - Look at [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WYdje.png), click on the arrow right of the *run* symbol and select *run configurations...*. There you find numerous configurations for the execution of each class you have yet executed from eclipse. I would assume there is something special about the settings for the execution of your PDFBox code, e.g. some special JRE to use or something similar. As I'm using eclipse/MS Windows, details may differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is ancient but just in case you're like me and Googling around trying to solve this, just update your configuration with the following under VM Options:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.awt.headlessLib=true
```

Comment: I am not doing this any recently, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer?  Gotta get those sweet sweet internet points.  And it'll help others find the answer.